# AHK - set a subroutine to trigger another subroutine by pressing its hotkey

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

Is it possible in AHK to set a subroutine to trigger another subroutine by pressing its hotkey (not goSub, or GoTo)

I have a script like this...

```
#If (WinActive("ahk_class XXX") || WinActive("ahk_class YYY")) && !GetKeyState("Space", "P")
8:: msgbox you hit 8
7:: msgbox you hit 7
6:: msgbox you hit 6
5:: msgbox you hit 5
4:: msgbox you hit 4
3:: msgbox you hit 3
2:: msgbox you hit 2
1:: msgbox you hit 1
```

and I would like another hotkey `g::` to trigger the `8` hotkey from within the AHK script, I know I could GoTo, but is it possible to trigger a hotkey instead?

Currently I have tried...

```
g Up::
SendInput{8 Down}{8 Up}
;SendInput {8 Down}{8 Up}
Return

with no result, it doesn't trigger the `8::` subroutine.
```

is it possible? thanks advanced.

If not possible, I have tried using GoTo, but this doesn't work...

```
$g::
GoTo, GoGroup1
Sleep 50
GoTo, ToolPset2
Return

GoGroup1:
some clicks
Return

ToolPset2:
some clicks
Return
```

cuz when pressing `g` it does Go to group1, but then it doesn't GoTo ToolPset2, why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `GoSub` instead of `Goto`, it should work.
Basically: `Gosub` returns, but `Goto` never comes back.

```
$g::
GoSub, GoGroup1
Sleep 50
GoSub, ToolPset2
Return

GoGroup1:
MsgBox 1
Return

ToolPset2:
MsgBox 2
Return
```

Comment: thanks man, could you please check out this question?? http://superuser.com/questions/1164320/autohotkey-how-to-launch-a-ahkscript-from-within-another-ahkscript thanksAdvanced.

Comment: It says the question was removed!? Btw I wrote that script for hotkeys that removed the menu bars, did the key presses respond smoothly?

Comment: Normally you send this message to either suspend or unsuspend a script,
(it toggles suspend on/off):
`PostMessage, 0x111, 65404,,, ahk_id %hWnd%`.
-- This link explains how to retrieve the suspend on/off
status of a script:
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/89284-turn-all-scripts-on-and-off/page-2#entry565650

Comment: yes thanks, that suspend unsuspend its done, I haven't try this question respond yet, Ill do it ASAP, thanks agian. btw can a AHK script flip horizontally (mirror horizontally) my main screen?? thanks advanced. http://superuser.com/questions/1164910/can-an-ahkscript-flip-horizontally-mirror-horizontally-my-main-screen-thanks

Comment: I don't know about flipping the screen horizontally.
Do you have a utility that can do this?
Then maybe AutoHotkey can tell the utility to do it.

Comment: No, I'm looking for an autohotkey script that could do that, please superuser community help me on this, thankss

Comment: -- AutoHotkey usually achieves things via the Winapi.
I don't know if the Winapi can do this.
-- Otherwise if you know of a utility that can do this,
then you might be able to communicate with it via AutoHotkey.
-- (I can't help you any more than that regarding flipping the screen horizontally.)
-- Are you working on a big project? Do you need it for gaming or something?

Comment: nope I'm just an illustrator n an a bit of programmer xD